# Running Meteor with external mongodb from Mac terminal

Tags: bash, mongodb, meteor

The following command is expected to run Meteor locally but connect to a mongodb on the cloud, but I am getting

> -bash: !3: event not found

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017/myDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=authDB meteor
```

Any idea how to start a local Meteor app with a mongodb on the cloud? thx

Comment: put url in quotes

Comment: `MONGO_URL="rest of it" meteor` gave same error.

Comment: escape special characters, or use single quotes. see http://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found

Comment: Yes. thx, that worked.